# SSH session dropping/freezing/ignoring keepalive

Tags: ssh, openssh

What does this output from `ssh -vvv` mean?

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
```

My sessions to a server are being dropped after approx 1 minute. This only ever happens for one particular server and the only difference in output of `ssh -vvv` is this line (above) appears in the output whereas it does not in all other correctly functioning ssh sessions which do not timeout / drop the connection.

My client side config:

```
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 1
    ServerAliveCountMax 1440
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

My server side config:

```
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 1
ClientAliveCountMax 10000

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Importantly they contain Server/Client AliveInterval and AliveCount lines.

Comment: did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @Adam unfortunately not - over a year on I don't recall which machine I saw this problem when connecting to either unfortunatly